# MySQL for Informatica 9.5

Tags: mysql, database, odbc, etl, informatica

Which version of MySQL to be installed for Informatica 9.5? I also want to know the steps to download, install and to integrate with Informatica as a database. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through the Informatica installation manual.

Comment: May be your SQL Server is not a genuine version. Try installation by using Oracle 11g it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[This note](https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/Pages/1/145276.aspx) says that as of Powercenter 9.0.1 only MySQL Enterprise Edition is supported as a source and target (not Community Edition). As far as I know this is also true of Powercenter 9.5.